# Why does uniform_int_distribution<uintmax_t> work for 62 bit numbers but not for 63 or 64 bit ones?

Tags: c++, c++11, libc++

I'm having difficulty understanding why this code, an attempt to use the new `<random>` header in C++11, is correctly generating random numbers in `[0, 2**62 - 1]` but not `[0, 2**63 - 1]` or `[0, 2**64 - 1]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <ctime>

static std::mt19937 engine; // Mersenne twister MT19937

void print_n_random_bits (unsigned int n);

int main (void) {
  engine.seed(time(0));
  print_n_random_bits(64);
  print_n_random_bits(63);
  print_n_random_bits(62);
  return 0;
}

void print_n_random_bits (unsigned int n)
{
  uintmax_t max;

  if (n == 8 * sizeof(uintmax_t)) {
    max = 0;
  } else {
    max = 1;
    max <<= n;
  }
  --max;

  std::uniform_int_distribution<uintmax_t> distribution(0, max);

  std::cout << n << " bits, max: " << max << std::endl;
  std::cout << distribution(engine) << std::endl;
}
```

Now, a bit more digging reveals `std::mt19937_64`, which has the correct behaviour, but can anyone explain to me why something that works for a 62 bit number doesn't work for a 64 bit one?

**Edit**: Sorry, I didn't even specify the problem. **The problem is that for 63 and 64 bit max values, the output is consistently a number in the range `[0, 2**32 - 1]`**, e.g.:

```
% ./rand                       
64 bits, max: 18446744073709551615
1803260654
63 bits, max: 9223372036854775807
3178301365
62 bits, max: 4611686018427387903
2943926730538475327

% ./rand                                
64 bits, max: 18446744073709551615
1525658116
63 bits, max: 9223372036854775807
2093351390
62 bits, max: 4611686018427387903
1513326512211312260

% ./rand                                                       
64 bits, max: 18446744073709551615
884934896
63 bits, max: 9223372036854775807
683284805
62 bits, max: 4611686018427387903
2333288494897435595
```

**Edit 2**: I'm using `clang++` (`Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1)`) and "libc++". I can't easily test the above with GCC as my version doesn't have `c++0x` support.

Comment: What exactly is it doing that's unexpected?  That is, how exactly is it presenting you with results that differ from your expectations?

Comment: Also, what standard library implementation are you using?

Comment: Consider its maybe just bad luck :)

Comment: With GCC4.5.1, all three tests (62/63/64 bits) return 32-bit values. http://www.ideone.com/3GZ9S

Comment: With GCC4.6.1, all three tests (62/63/64 bits) return 64-bit values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You've found a bug in libc++.  Thanks!!!

I have committed the following fix to tip-of-trunk revision 143104:

```
Index: include/algorithm
===================================================================
--- include/algorithm   (revision 143102)
+++ include/algorithm   (working copy)
@@ -2548,7 +2548,7 @@
         {
             __u = __e_() - _Engine::min();
         } while (__u >= __y0_);
-        if (__w0_ < _EDt)
+        if (__w0_ < _WDt)
             _S <<= __w0_;
         else
             _S = 0;
@@ -2561,7 +2561,7 @@
         {
             __u = __e_() - _Engine::min();
         } while (__u >= __y1_);
-        if (__w0_ < _EDt - 1)
+        if (__w0_ < _WDt - 1)
             _S <<= __w0_ + 1;
         else
             _S = 0;
```

This fix does not require a recompile of the binary libc++.dylib.

Comment: Does that algorithm used in libc++ has any known name to read about it?

Comment: I don't know.  The algorithm is specified in the standard spec for independent_bits_engine.

Answer (score 0):

Since `std::mt19937` is the 32-bit version, most likely what's happening is it's making assumptions about which bits do and do not matter in its "work space" when generating the next number. This then results in overflow when generating numbers that could including those last two bits. I suspect that you'd find the actual distribution is not really uniform with max numbers higher than `2**32 - 1` on the 32 bit engine.

Comment: Not sure about this. Brief investigations suggest that the distribution is uniform or as-near-as-damnit with max of `2**62 - 1`, based on 1,000,000 generated integers.

Comment: Even if `mt19937` returns 32-bit numbers, shouldn't `uniform_int_distribution` call it multiple times to create 62/63/64-bit numbers?